# Install GeoIP Nginx module - Debian

Tags: nginx, debian, geoip, maxmind

I'm seeking your help to install the Nginx GeoIP module, and all its dependencies. 
Actually, i tried a lot if things to build Nginx with it, but failed each time on same error.

**My config:** 
`Debian 8.2`, `Nginx 1.9.7-1~jessie` (last mainline), `PHP7 RC7`.

**What i did:**

- Installed `geoip-api-c` 1.6.7 from source
- Try apt-get install directly `geoip-bin` package, failed as "already uptodate").
- Installed module `libmaxminddb` from git

A `ldconfig -p | grep maxminddb` command give me :

```
libmaxminddb.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmaxminddb.so.0
libmaxminddb.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmaxminddb.so
```

Everything looks fine.

But on nginx `dpkg-buildpackage -b`, one libmaxminddb check fail with :

```
dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libmaxminddb.so.0 (used by debian/nginx/usr/sbin/nginx)
Hint: check if the library actually comes from a package.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/nginx.substvars debian/nginx/usr/sbin/nginx returned exit code 2
debian/rules:11: recipe for target 'binary' failed
```

I really tested everything, installed all lib again from source, tried to install from ubuntu PPA & didnt found any debian repo URL to add to my list.
Just to know, i tried :

```
apt-get install libmaxminddb0 libmaxminddb-dev mmdb-bin
```

Fail with packet not found. 
Regarding this, i removed geoip `--add-module` before nginx build and the build-package worked perfectly.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore missing info warnings by using
`dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info`

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992359 solved same problem for me